# Accessing Amazon s3 bucket via Amazon console which is created via java api

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have created a Amazon S3 bucket via java api. Is there a way to access the bucket via Amazon S3 console??

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a permissions issue, there should be no problem seeing and manipulating the bucket from the S3 Console. AWS does not make any distinction regarding how a resource is created with regard to how the resource can be accessed. You can create a bucket in the Console and access it via the Java SDK or vice versa.

Make sure that you are using the same credentials in the Java code as you are when logging into the Console.

Comment: I have access key and secret key. Can i access AWS console only with this credentials??

Comment: I think you need the password to access the Console. The access key can be used with command-line interface and any of the SDKs. The user which the access key is associated with can certainly have a password turned on for it, if it does not have it already.